# How to use java to check if an xml file exists? If not - create it

Tags: java, android, xml, file

Something along the lines of

```
if(!getContentView(R.layout.mainfile).exits){
  //create the xml file in the layout folder here
  setContentView(R.layout.mainfile);
  initvar();
}
else
{
initvar();
}
```

Another small question is: can I generate any XML file from nothing with Java? (yes or no question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources (XMLs in the /res directory) the generated `R.java` refers to are compiled into a resources.arsc file, so these XML files are not even accessible like a normal file on the device. Moreover, the 'if exists' statement is done at compile time: if you're referring to a resource in your code that does is not defined, it will not compile. So no need to check at runtime.

In a general sense, you can load XML files from your device using e.g. a [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) and then passing that to a `LayoutInflater.inflate()` in the case of a layout file. Not sure why you would want to do that though.

Comment: well i need to create this: a person opens the program for the first time, it asks him to list off all the rooms he has. Then for every room it creates a layout with elements. Then it saves this to preferences. Next time he opens the program, it auto-opens the xml file with the rooms. Also he can open preferences and add more rooms, so the program would edit the xml to add the new layout for the room (or delete old and generate a new xml with +1 layout). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: As I understand it, all you need is a ListView-type layout that will be populated with a View for each room. It basically boils down to inflating one "generic" View that contains the relevant elements (e.g. an EditText for the size of the room) and setting the values of the elements from the saved 'preferences'. This does not require a different layout each time, but only one of which you tweak the parameters using the data you saved previously. In other words, you create many Views in the ListView from one layout definition.

Comment: Thing is i need to see them all at the same time since they display the temperature in the room. So atm I have a LinearLayout(h) with LinearLayouts(v) in it. I made them all clickable so if you click them, that layour turns orange, becomes wider and + - buttons appear to change the temperature.

Comment: Not sure i can visualize exactly what you want. Either way, you can inflate a view from a layout and add that to one of the linear layouts for each of the rooms. Still, a ListView sounds more practical: you can have a dialog or new activity where you edit the item when you click on it. Or use the functionality and optional hierarchy that a PreferenceActivity provides.

Comment: http://i1102.photobucket.com/albums/g457/rvdincowform/distancinis.png
the 4 room names are on top, the two text views are Temperature now and the temperature that you want(you set it with + -). The auto button makes the menu pop up.

Comment: I would probably go for a different layout approach, as this design is flawed in a sense that it can only hold a limited number of rooms. But  if I had to do it this way, I'd probably add a View holding the 'summary' for each room in a horizontal `LinearLayout`. When the room is pressed, I'd `remove` the view from the `LinearLayout` and `inflate` a 'complete' view with the +/- buttons and populate the values and add that to the LinearLayout.

Comment: oh well. I figured i'll make 1 layout type for the selected room and 1 for a non-selected. And yes, sadly it has to be this way. Not my choice =/ Oh well.. gave you the vote for all your help.

Comment: Cheers for that; I would consider posting a new question with the description you have in the comments here. There might be a more elegant solution for this type of layout behavour someone else knows of. Good luck.